# How many byte read the std::istream::peek() function

Tags: c++, file

I have try to read the next character in a file with only characters and with a file with only integers. This function return the next value (int or char). Now the question is how many byte read peek()? For first file it seems read one byte while for the second file it seems read four byte. How it's possible?

Comment: Because the size of an `int` is usually 32 bits, or *four bytes*.

Comment: Also, posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) goes a long way to getting a good answer.

Comment: Which function? I can't see a function here. Your file contains _bytes_, period; `peek()` reads a _byte_. If your bytes can be interpreted, via conversion from ASCII, as decimal numbers, that's another story.

Comment: Yes but if I use peek() and the next character is a char read only byte.

Comment: No, `peek()` _always_ reads a byte. Because your file data consists of bytes. There is nothing else there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [H]ow many byte[s are] read [by] `peek()`?

[**`std::ifstream::peek()` reads one character (i.e. one byte) from the file**, and returns it inside an `int`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c40c43ef1953a77) (the use of `int` is so that there is sufficient range to conditionally return `EOF`).

*(Other `std::basic_istream` specialisations may have different `char_type` and `int_type` aliases, so the exact types and numbers given may differ if you use them. But the key is still that you extract one **character**, even if you think your ASCII file contains "numbers".)*

It doesn't matter what the bytes of your file are: human-readable ASCII text, human-readable ASCII numbers, an encoded ZIP, random values… `std::ifstream::peek()` is an "unformatted input function", which is a type of IOStream function that works on the *characters* in a file.

> For first file it seems read one byte while for the second file it seems read four byte.
>   How it's possible?

It's not. You did something wrong.

Comment: Because when I get downvote no non comment me. So **the bold** is for bold my wonder. Other than your answer is not understandable even for me.

Comment: @k-five: I wrote two comments explaining why I downvoted your answer.

Comment: @k-five: Not sure what you mean by "even for me". This is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: And your comment *No, peek() always reads a byte. Because your file data consists of bytes. There is nothing else there* is more better.

Comment: @k-five: Glad you enjoyed it.

Comment: thanks for commenting me. I appreciate that. Always do it

Comment: Yes, you're right. I could read number in a file where I put int because this int were small(one byte were sufficiently). I try a put a big number and with peek don't return this big number but another number(only first byte).

Comment: @Chuck94: I'm always right ;)

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on the type of stream.

`peek()` will read one character, however streams have *traits* associated with them that dictate what is considered a character. The `char_traits` on a stream controls this.

Here's a handy guide:

```
char    : always 1 byte
wchar_t : platform defined. dictated by its *underlying type* Likely 4 bytes
char32_t: at least 4 bytes
char16_t: at least 2 bytes
```

[`fstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) is actually a `basic_fstream<char>` meaning that it will read the same number of bytes as `sizeof(char)`, which is 1 byte. It will return `int_type` which is also controlled through *traits*

Comment: This is the return type but the actual number of "characters" read is always _one_ (i.e. `sizeof(char_type)` bytes) - the integer type is used for making space for `EOF`

Comment: _"it will read the same number of bytes as sizeof(int)"_ Wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You make a great point. Will update.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c40c43ef1953a77

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, **If you know the correct answer why do not you put yours?**

Comment: @k-five: The correct answer? Heck, I'm not even sure that we know what the _question_ is yet. Also I like to try to help others to refine their own answers (that is the entire purpose of the comments section, after all), but, fine if I must. **Why the bold?**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Updated.